# How can I get Safari 5.1 to show the download window?

Tags: macos, safari, accessibility

I know that I can simply click the downloads icon next to the search bar, however I'm visually impaired and have trouble using the mouse (I can't find it, miss click), therefore I'm much faster with the keyboard.

I'm wondering how I can show and focus the downloads manager in Safari 5.1 just like in prior versions.

Comment: Apple clearly took that window from safari but there is now a better key command to get at the folder in Finder. Have you tried that avenue in case it meets your needs? It will be easier than re-working a script alternative, but FastScripts might be the best option.

Comment: Thanks bmike, I may look into this. I do use spotlight to get to my Downloads currently, though sometimes spotlight finds other things too, this solution could be a neat option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could follow the advice of Red Sweater[^1](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1949/restore-safaris-downloads-keyboard-shortcut) and use AppleScript + FastScript/Sparkle. If you follow the link everything is explained in details.

Comment: Sounds like a workable solution, will try and see how this one goes. Can't believe Apple removed an accessibility feature. Accessibility is one reason I don't use windows, I hope this isn't a trend for apple.

Comment: It's not a trend, just one instance where general usability did force those using accessibility to adapt/reimpliment. If it helps, the vision centric users have a ton of Lion changes to adapt to. Several default controls are gone, directions changed, everything got shuffled in spaces just for starters!

Comment: Thanks bmike, I may have to look through them. My visual impairment rather gray as my eyes shake I have trouble focussing, I'm almost blind in my left eye and also have no peripheral vision, so I can only see the direct portion of screen in front of me (I sit about 8" from the screen).

Comment: I still haven't implemented this bmike, but plan to soon, I must apologise, my wife is in hospital at the moment and my priorities have been around her, sorry if you feel I might be delaying.

Comment: Excellent, worked brilliantly I've always used CMD+J though, not sure where he got CMD+OPT+L from :)

Answer (score 3):

The same keyboard shortcut for opening Downloads in the Finder works to show and hide the Downloads window within Safari (I'm using 5.1.1).

The shortcut is <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>

Note: If you're entering text in a form, open the Downloads window then close it, Safari has trouble returning focus to the form item I was in despite still showing the blue focus ring.

Comment: Yeah ⌥⌘L was removed in 5.1 but restored in 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Full Keyboard Access Enabled you can press Tab till you arrive on the icon & then press space to view

Comment: Pressing TAB a random number of times to get to a function hardly sounds efficient. I do have full keyboard access on, however identifying which element is focussed isn't always straightforward when you have bad eyes.

Comment: THe number of times isn't random, when you're in topsides it always starts from the back button, then it depends on how many icons you have

Comment: if there are controls on the page it "seems" random as it first tabs through the page then to the back button.

Comment: Slightly tangental, but VoiceOver can also help identify the focused control, if you have vision issues... it can read it out on demand.